# Can't get form preventDefault to work

Tags: jquery, forms

I've read a lot of other posts but I seem to be doing something wrong entirely as I just cannot get my form submit to work with `preventDefault()`.

My form:

```
<form class="form-inline" id="formsubmit">
    <div class="form-group">
        <!--some stuff-->
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="margin-top:10px">
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#formsubmit').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log('Prevented')
    })
})
```

This still reloads the page.

EDIT:
Working now. Strangely it works when it is the first function in the `<script>`. It does not work when placed behind 2 google visualisation charts.

Comment: Just sounds like you are adding form to the DOM after document is ready. Read about [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: why you tagged this question in node.js ?

Comment: @ Dineshaws Oh sorry had some more stuff in the question but took it out for simplicity. @ A. Wolff I've considered it but thought I had it right. Will look at it again.

Comment: @SecondLemon if so use event delegation method.

Comment: @alirezasafian This is optional here

Answer (score -1):

This works:

https://jsfiddle.net/67e7vxar/1/

HTML:

```
<form id = "ff">
  <input type = "text"><br/>
  <input type = "submit" value = "submit">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#ff').on('submit', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
  alert('Default prevented');
});
```

Comment: It works on fiddle for me too but not on my site. Ill copy the whole thing into fiddle to see if I can replicate it.

Comment: At least the error message tells me something here: https://jsfiddle.net/5s0ek2oq/embedded/result/

Comment: I made the script load later and included jquery for the fiddle. So your problem is that you are probably loading the script too early or something.

Comment: Ah lol of course. Let me see why it is working here then and not in my script. (didn't get that error anyway)